# Socket creation error in SpagoBI 5.2

Tags: windows-10

I want to create a cockpit in spagoBi 5.2 using a data set but I got an error message : " Socket creation error " . What could be the cause(s) of this problem ?

Comment: There isn't enough detail in this question for it to be answerable. I'd recommend that you [edit] it to include the exact steps required to reproduce the problem. Your question will be better received if you also show some evidence of what you've already reasearched/tried to resolve the issue. See [How to Ask] and unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5015/22812

Comment: Thank you for your help. the problem is resolved